# How to simulate spaceBetween behavior in a listView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layoutbuilder, flutter-responsive-layout

I have a Column of items like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    ...items,
    Spacer(),
    Footer(),
  ],
)
```

However, the `items` list may be dynamic, which makes necessary use a `ListView` instead of `Column`. The only problem is that my `Footer` was separated with an`Spacer`, the `Spacer` widget will throw error if its used in a ListView.

What can I use to give the effect of a `Column` to my `ListView` when are just a few items that not filled all the screen?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the `items`?

Comment: A Container with a predefined height and width and color, nothing fancy

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(items),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Footer(),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: But how did you manage to give the Space which was earlier provided by `Spacer` ? I guess this solution will place the `Footer` on the top of the remaining space

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add that I had to set my Footer in a ```Column``` with ```MainAxisAlignment.end```

Answer (score 0):

*You can use* **SizeBox(heigth:your hieght)** *instead of* **Spacer();**

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue I had a lot when I was still learning.

I think you have a same issue,

Step 1: You shouldn't use `SingleChildScrollView` as a parent of that `Column`.

Step 2: Use `Expanded` Widget inside the `Column`.

Step 3: Inside the `Expanded` use another `Column` and put those `items`.

For example:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
       children: [
         ...items,
      ],
    ),
    Footer(),
  ],
)
```

You can have the scroll behaviour for that 2nd `Column` by giving `SingleChildScrollView` or use any `ListView`